# Reflexive Tripleability Theorem in Riehl's Category Theory in Context

Tags: category-theory, monads

Exercise 5.5.iii in Riehl's *[Category Theory in Context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)* consists in proving the following result:

> **Proposition 5.5.8** (RTT). If $U: \mathsf{D} \rightarrow \mathsf{C}$ has a left adjoint and if
>
> 1. $\mathsf{D}$ has coequalizers of reflexive¹ pairs,
> 2. $U$ preserves coequalizers of reflexive pairs, and
> 3. $U$ reflects isomorphisms,
>    then $U$ is monadic.
>
> ---
>
> ¹ A parallel pair $f,g:A\rightrightarrows B$ is *reflexive* if both maps admit a common section $s:B\to A$.

I tried to show that these conditions imply the precise tripleability condition in Theorem 5.5.1 from Riehl's text, i.e., that conditions 1, 2, 3 of Proposition 5.5.8 imply that $U$ creates coequalizers of $U$-split pairs, but I have been unable to achieve this. How should one proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out it suffices to check 1+2+3 imply that $U$ creates coequalizers of *reflexive* $U$-split pairs [[ref](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462390/101848)]. On the one hand, 1+2 imply that $U$ has all coequalizers for all reflexive $U$-split pairs, and that it preserves them. It is left to show that $U$ reflects coequalizers of reflexive $U$-split pairs. But $U$ is conservative, so we are done by application of [this result](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor#ConservativeFunctorsReflectLimitsWhichTheyPreserve).